# Excel Macro sends email and deletes row when command button is clicked, creates new sheet to do so. Doesn't work in shared worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

We're designing a spreadsheet that is used by two departments to pass work over from yDepartment to xDepartment, once yDepartment has completed the first part of the work.

We've set up an automatic email to get sent from yDepartment containing data being moved from one sheet to the other. To do this, the information is copied into a temporary worksheet which is deleted after sending the email (this is so that multiple and non-adjacent rows can be sent over at the same time).

This was all working fine until we shared the workbook, and running the macro resulted in the following error:

```
Run time error ‘1004’:
Delete method of Worksheet class failed
```

I've copied our code below (it's a bit of a Frankenstein I'm afraid)

```
Sub Pass_to_xDepartment()

Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo Whoops

'Declare variables
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim WSheet As Variant
Dim DTable As Variant
Dim Sendrng As Range
Dim sht3 As Worksheet

'MsgBox when passing over work
If MsgBox("Do you want to pass the selected work to xDepartment?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please ensure selected work is complete." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This will generate an automatic email to xDepartment.", vbYesNo, "Pass to xDepartment") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

For Each WSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        If WSheet.FilterMode Then
            WSheet.ShowAllData
        End If
    End If
    For Each DTable In WSheet.ListObjects
        If DTable.ShowAutoFilter Then
            DTable.Range.AutoFilter
            DTable.Range.AutoFilter
        End If
    Next DTable
Next WSheet

'Set variables
Set sht1 = Sheets("yDepartment")
Set sht2 = Sheets("xDepartment")

'Move row to destination sheet & Delete source row
lastRow = sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Select Entire Row.Resize(ColumnSize:=12)
Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Selection.Parent.Columns("N")).Value = Date

With Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Selection.Parent.Range("A:N"))
    .Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
    lastRow2 = sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .EntireRow.Delete
End With

Set sht3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
sht3.Name = "temp"
'Note: if the selection is one cell it will send the whole worksheet
Set Sendrng = sht2.Range("A" & (lastRow + 1) & ":N" & lastRow2)
Sendrng.Copy Destination:=sht3.Range("A1")

 On Error GoTo StopMacro

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Create the mail and send it
sht3.Activate
lastRow2 = sht3.Range("A" & sht3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Sendrng = sht3.Range("A1:N" & lastRow2)

With Sendrng

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With .Parent.MailEnvelope

        ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
        ' some header text to the email body.
        .Introduction = "Dear xDepartment," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The following work has been completed." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please see the shared spreadsheet for further details." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind regards," & vbNewLine & "yDepartment" & vbNewLine

        With .Item
            .To = "email"
            .CC = "email"
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "New work passed over from yDepartment"
            .Send
        End With

    End With
End With

StopMacro:

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("temp").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
Worksheets("yDepartment").Activate
MsgBox ("Tours have been passed to xDepartment.")

Whoops:
 Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Does anyone know how to either avoid this error and allow us to delete the temporary sheet while the workbook is shared, or else how to edit the macro to make it compatible with the workbook being shared? Is there another way to get the email to send, without having to create the temporary sheet? I think that was the only way that we had worked out how to be able to select multiple and non-adjacent rows at the same time to be passed over.

Any and all help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete sheets in a shared workbook, so I'd suggest you leave the temp sheet in there (you can hide it if need be) and simply reuse it each time, then clear the contents. For example:

```
Sub Pass_to_xDepartment()

Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo Whoops

'Declare variables
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim WSheet As Variant
Dim DTable As Variant
Dim Sendrng As Range
Dim sht3 As Worksheet

'MsgBox when passing over work
If MsgBox("Do you want to pass the selected work to xDepartment?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please ensure selected work is complete." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This will generate an automatic email to xDepartment.", vbYesNo, "Pass to xDepartment") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

For Each WSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        If WSheet.FilterMode Then
            WSheet.ShowAllData
        End If
    End If
    For Each DTable In WSheet.ListObjects
        If DTable.ShowAutoFilter Then
            DTable.Range.AutoFilter
            DTable.Range.AutoFilter
        End If
    Next DTable
Next WSheet

'Set variables
Set sht1 = Sheets("yDepartment")
Set sht2 = Sheets("xDepartment")

'Move row to destination sheet & Delete source row
lastRow = sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Select Entire Row.Resize(ColumnSize:=12)
Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Selection.Parent.Columns("N")).Value = Date

With Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Selection.Parent.Range("A:N"))
    .Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
    lastRow2 = sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .EntireRow.Delete
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set sht3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("temp")
On Error GoTo 0
If sht3 Is Nothing Then
    Set sht3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    sht3.Name = "temp"
Else
    sht3.UsedRange.Clear
End If
'Note: if the selection is one cell it will send the whole worksheet
Set Sendrng = sht2.Range("A" & (lastRow + 1) & ":N" & lastRow2)
Sendrng.Copy Destination:=sht3.Range("A1")

 On Error GoTo StopMacro

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Create the mail and send it
sht3.Activate
lastRow2 = sht3.Range("A" & sht3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Sendrng = sht3.Range("A1:N" & lastRow2)

With Sendrng

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With .Parent.MailEnvelope

        ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
        ' some header text to the email body.
        .Introduction = "Dear xDepartment," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The following work has been completed." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please see the shared spreadsheet for further details." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind regards," & vbNewLine & "yDepartment" & vbNewLine

        With .Item
            .To = "email"
            .CC = "email"
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "New work passed over from yDepartment"
            .Send
        End With

    End With
End With

StopMacro:

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
Worksheets("yDepartment").Activate
MsgBox ("Tours have been passed to xDepartment.")

Whoops:
 Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Rory, sorry I didn't get back to you when you answered - Christmas holidays. I don't suppose you could explain how I would write that in the code? Sorry, I'm very much a novice at this and find it all quite difficult to wade through.

Comment: That's fantastic! As an aside, do you know how to paste special as opposed to the regular paste which is overwriting some conditional formatting we have on the destination sheet? If we can manage to make the macro paste special (Paste Values) then this should not overwrite the conditional formatting, right? Thank you!

Comment: @LizH instead of: `.Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)` use two lines:`.Copy` and then `sht2.Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Pastespecial xlpastevalues`